# How To Test Object expression methods by mocking external dependency which its mothod is using?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mockk

**While writing unit tests, `@InjectMock` creates an instance of the class and injects the mocked instances defined using `@Mock`.**

So this works fine when we are testing methods of a class. **I have a problem while testing methods of an object expression.**

For example:
I have an object class DbService.

```
object DbService {
    private lateinit var connection: Connection
    init {
        makeConnection()
    }
    private fun makeConnection(){
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Users", "user", "password")
        }catch (ex: Exception){
            println(ex)
        }
    }

    fun checkConnection(){
        var preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SHOW DATABASES;")
        var resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()
        while(resultSet.next()){
            println(resultSet.getObject(1))
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to test `checkConnection` function. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually doing some more research, I got some hints and it worked for me.

It's like, you can do manual dependency injection using the setter method.

[setter-based Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-setter-injection)

so what I did, **I added one more function to manually set the connection object like this.**

```
object DbService {
    private lateinit var connection: Connection
    init {
        makeConnection()
    }
    private fun makeConnection(){
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Users", "user", "password")
        }catch (ex: Exception){
            println(ex)
        }
    }
    
    // setter based dependency injection            <----
    fun initializeConnectionObject(conn: Connection){
        connection = conn
    }

    fun printingSomeMoreData(){
        var statement: Statement
        var resultSet: ResultSet
        var preparedStatement: PreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM titles where title=?;")
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "Engineer")
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()
        val columnCount = resultSet.metaData.columnCount
        while(resultSet.next()){
            for(i in 1..columnCount){
                print(resultSet.getObject(i).toString() + " ")
            }
            println()
        }
    }

}
```

with the tests like:

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
    class DbServiceTest {

    private lateinit var dbService: DbService
    @Mock lateinit var mockedConnection: Connection
    @Mock lateinit var mockedPreparedStatement: PreparedStatement
    @Mock lateinit var mockedResultSet: ResultSet
    @Mock
    lateinit var mockedResultSetMetaData: ResultSetMetaData

    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(true)
    }

    @Test
    fun printingSomeMoreDataTest() {
        dbService = DbService
        Mockito.`when`(mockedResultSetMetaData.columnCount).thenReturn(3)
        Mockito.`when`(mockedResultSet.next()).thenReturn(true, true, true, true, false)
        Mockito.`when`(mockedResultSet.metaData).thenReturn(mockedResultSetMetaData)
        Mockito.`when`(mockedResultSet.getObject(1)).thenReturn("11", "21", "31", "41")
        Mockito.`when`(mockedResultSet.getObject(2)).thenReturn("12", "22", "32", "42")
        Mockito.`when`(mockedResultSet.getObject(3)).thenReturn("13", "23", "33", "43")
        Mockito.`when`(mockedPreparedStatement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(mockedResultSet)
        Mockito.`when`(mockedConnection.prepareStatement(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockedPreparedStatement)
        dbService.initializeConnectionObject(mockedConnection)      // <----
        dbService.printingSomeMoreData()
        Mockito.verify(mockedResultSet, times(12)).getObject(anyInt())

    }
}
```